# Simple Diffy-Q problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integration

So as a fun project, I'm trying to work my way through Kreyzig's "Advanced Engineering Mathematics". But I've gotten to a really simple problem:
$$xy' = 2y$$

where I know the solution is $x^2$ but for the life of me I can't figure out how to integrate this really simple problem properly. I keep ending up with:$$\lg(x) = 1/2\lg(2y), $$

but I don't think that's right. Help?

Comment: $dy/y=2dx/x$ so $\ln y=2\ln x +C$ and $y=e^{2\ln x +C}=Kx^2$

Comment: Observe that for $y(x):=c\ \text e^{\int^x f(t)\text dt}$ you have $\frac{\text d}{\text d x}y(x)=f(x)\ y(x)$. Your equation is of that type, with $f(x)=\tfrac{2}{x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis is a problem where we may use separation of variables. That is we begin by moving the $x$ terms to the right side and $y$ terms to the left so that we have $$\frac{y'}{y} = \frac{2}{x}.$$

We then integrate both sides  and have $$\int \frac{1}{y} dy = \int \frac{2}{x} dx$$ which results in $$ln(y) =2\ln(x) + C.$$ Solving for $y$ by exponentiating both sides yields $$y=e^{\ln(x^2) + c} = e^{\ln(x^2)}e^c = Ax^2$$ where $A = e^c$.

Comment: How did you go from 2ln(x) to ln(x2)? I know that must be a property of logs...

Comment: Logarithms of any base satisfy $\log x + \log y= \log (xy)$.

Comment: One of the properties of logarithms is that $a \ln(x) = \ln(x^a)$. For this particular example, $2\ln(x) = \ln(x) + \ln(x) = \ln(x \cdot x) = \ln(x^2)$.